# How can I combine an in place transformation, and a copy transformation?

Tags: c++, function, templates, overloading, c++17

I would like to combine these two functionalities into a single function interface:

```
T& Transform(T & foo){
   //transform t
   return t;
}

T As_Transformed(T foo){
   //transform t
   return t;
}
```

Sometimes I want to transform a variable passed into the function.
Other times I want a new variable with the applied transformation.

As a result, I end up creating two functions everytime, and following a made up convention of mine where `As_` takes and returns a copy, while not having `As_` takes and returns a reference.

How can I write a single function implementation that will handle both of these behaviors?

I have no requirements on what it should look like, but I'd like to have a way where I'm not relying on my `As_` convention, and ideally where I only make one function instead of two.

---

**Example:**
Here is an example of what this would look like.
Let's take `Uppercase()` and `As_Upercased()`

```
std::string str1 = "hello";
Uppercase(str1); //str is now "HELLO"

std::string str2 = "hello";
auto str3 = As_Uppercased(str2); //str2 is still "hello", 
                                 //but str3 is "HELLO"
```

I don't know what the combined interface would look like, but perhaps:

```
std::string str1 = "hello";
Uppercase<REF>(str1); //str is now "HELLO"

std::string str2 = "hello";
auto str3 = Uppercase<COPY>(str2); //str2 is still "hello", 
                                   //but str3 is "HELLO"
```

Or maybe I can do something with reference wrappers.
The possible implementations of this, are what I'm asking about.

Comment: If the functions have the same name - how do you expect the compiler to figure out which one you wanted to call? If you keep different names and avoid repeating yourself - implement `As_Transformed` as 'make a copy', call 'Transformed' and return the transformed copy

Comment: @Rostislav The same function name can be kept through templates or function overloading.  Your suggestion is what I do already, but I'd like too avoid it if possible.  I've considered reference wrappers on the inputs, or a COPY / REF type for template dispatching.  I'm curious if others have any elegant solutions.

Comment: These functions are doing two different things.  I would not want them to have the same name to reduce confusion.

Comment: @AnonMail Conceptually, they are the same transformation. One applies the transformation in place to the input parameter; the other returns a copy of the transformation.  Whether this is a good practice or not, is debatable, but I'd like to see implementations of how it could be done.

Comment: I think for anyone to answer your question you need to show the example usages where the different logic (copy/no-copy) is to be executed.

Comment: @Rostislav thanks.  added an example usage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can tell the compiler how to differentiate the two by providing an overload on `std::reference_wrapper`. Then the code would look like this, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using T = std::string;

T Transform(T t)
{
    t += " copy";
    return t;
}

std::reference_wrapper<T> Transform(std::reference_wrapper<T> t)
{
    t.get() += " ref";
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    T t{"original"};

    std::cout << Transform(Transform(t)) << "\n";
    std::cout << t << "\n";
    std::cout << Transform(Transform(std::ref(t))).get() << "\n";
    std::cout << t;
}
```

Output:

```
original copy copy
original
original ref ref
original ref ref
```

Notice, how the original value is left intact after the first call chain and is modified after the second one.

In your actual code, the first overload would just call the second to transform its passed-by-copy parameter wrapped using `std::ref` to avoid code duplication.

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/RLMAH8577)

Comment: Shouldn't the `Transform` that takes a `reference_wrapper` return a `T&` not a `reference_wrapper`?  That means you have to `ref` on reach recursion, but it also means that the returned data isn't magical anymore.

Comment: @Yakk It surely can, but at least with `std::string`, the chaining doesn't work as expected - the first overload is called for the outer call in `Transform(Transform(std::ref(t))`. The best viable function selection in this case is a bit puzzling (and interesting to figure out), but both [clang](http://rextester.com/WHBE39065) and gcc agree that this is how it's supposed to be.

Comment: @Yakk I guess copy constructor is considered to be a better match than a converting one. Gotta dig a bit to confirm this to myself :)

Comment: @Yakk Seems like the first one is an l-value transformation which is better than the second case of user-defined conversion.

Comment: yes, `T` wins out over `reference_wrapper` for a number of reasons (for one thing, `reference_wrapper` is not deduced).  If they want to do it by-ref, they should repeat the `std::ref`: `Transform(std::ref(Transform(std::ref(bob)))` in my opinion.

Comment: @Yakk Well, in this case `T` is not a template parameter, but a specific type (following a little strange OP's code). But given a little theoretical nature of the OP's question I'll leave that up to him in case he really wants to implement this. Thanks for the feedback anyway!

Comment: This is really neat. And would solve a lot of unnecessary *_copy functions. BUT my measurements show  `std::reference_wrapper<T> ` to be significantly slower than a straight function taking a reference. My tests were doing `strtoupper(std::string& s)` and `trim(std::string& s)` ... does that makes sense? it would be a shame.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot combine them because they don't do the same thing. One modifies the object passed to the function and the other keeps the original object unmodified. One makes a copy of the object and returns it, the other returns a reference to the original object. Those things are contradictory requirements.

But, one can be implemented using the other, so that there is no duplication of logic.

```
T As_Transformed(T t){
   Transform(t);
   return t;
}
```

The above will be identical for any other function similar to `Transform`, so, if you want to avoid duplicating the boilerplate, you could generalize it as a template and use that instead:

```
template<class T, class Func>
auto copy_and_call(T copy, Func&& function) {
    function(copy);
    return copy;
}
```

You could call that like:

```
T t;
auto copy = copy_and_call(t, Transform);
```

Then again, if the number of functions for which you need both forms is high but the number of function calls is low, then perhaps this doesn't warrant declaring a function. You could easily simply use `Transform` on a copy instead of doing that in a function. The following is not a lot of code.

```
T t = "original"; // let's say T can be constructed from a string literal
T copy = t;
Transform(copy);
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a namespace-based alternative:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

namespace inplace {
std::string& lowercase(std::string& src) {
  std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), src.begin(), ::tolower);
  return src;
}
} // namespace inplace

std::string lowercase(std::string src) {
  return inplace::lowercase(src);
}
```

That way, the function names are identical and their interfaces are identical, but the namespace clearly defines what you intend to do:

```
int main() {
  std::string a = "ThIs Is A sTrInG";
  std::string b = "ThIs Is AnOtHeR sTrInG";

  // it is clear that I intend to lowercase-in-place
  inplace::lowercase(a);

  // I can document that, in the absence of namespace, all mutations
  // create a copy
  auto c = lowercase(b);

  std::cout << "a: " << a << "\n"
            << "b: " << b << "\n"
            << "c: " << c << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
a: this is a string
b: ThIs Is AnOtHeR sTrInG
c: this is another string
```

Notice that **it is not possible** for the user to issue the directive

```
using namespace inplace;
```

because it would result in ambiguity; this is a portion of the compilation error:

```
error: call of overloaded 'lowercase(std::__cxx11::string&)' is ambiguous
   auto c = lowercase(b);
                       ^
```

So, the compiler will **ensure** that you must use the fully qualified name of the `inplace` functions.

The following code shows a collection of string mutations and their make-a-copy counterparts.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

namespace inplace {

bool is_not_space(char c) {
  return not std::isspace(c);
}

inline std::string& uppercase(std::string& src) {
  std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), src.begin(), ::toupper);
  return src;
}

inline std::string& lowercase(std::string& src) {
  std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), src.begin(), ::tolower);
  return src;
}

// Credit for the idea of ltrim, rtrim, and trim goes to Stackoverflow
// user Evan Teran: http://stackoverflow.com/users/13430/evan-teran
inline std::string& ltrim(std::string& src) {
  src.erase(src.begin(), std::find_if(src.begin(), src.end(), is_not_space));
  return src;
}

inline std::string& rtrim(std::string& src) {
  src.erase(std::find_if(src.rbegin(), src.rend(), is_not_space).base(), src.end());
  return src;
}

inline std::string& trim(std::string& src) {
  return ltrim(rtrim(src));
}

inline std::string& normalize(std::string& src) {
  return lowercase(trim(src));
}

}

// The create-a-copy versions simply forward the call to the in-place
// versions after having taken their argument by value.
inline std::string lowercase(std::string src) { return inplace::lowercase(src); }
inline std::string uppercase(std::string src) { return inplace::uppercase(src); }
inline std::string ltrim(std::string src)     { return inplace::ltrim(src);     }
inline std::string rtrim(std::string src)     { return inplace::rtrim(src);     }
inline std::string trim(std::string src)      { return inplace::trim(src);      }
inline std::string normalize(std::string src) { return inplace::normalize(src); }

int main() {

  std::string a = "ThIs Is A sTrInG";
  std::string b = "ThIs Is AnOtHeR sTrInG";

  // it is clear that I intend to lowercase-in-place
  inplace::lowercase(a);

  // I can document that, in the absence of namespace, all mutations
  // create a copy
  auto c = lowercase(b);

  std::cout << "a: " << a << "\n"
            << "b: " << b << "\n"
            << "c: " << c << "\n";

  std::string d = "     I NEED to normaliZE ThIs StrINg\r\n\t\t  ";
  std::string e = "\t\t\n\rAnD THIS one Too        \n\t\t     ";

  // again: transparent that I will do this in-place
  inplace::normalize(d);

  auto f = normalize(e);

  std::cout << "-->" << d << "<--\n"
            << "-->" << e << "<--\n"
            << "-->" << f << "<--\n";

}
```

Result:

```
a: this is a string
b: ThIs Is AnOtHeR sTrInG
c: this is another string
-->i need to normalize this string<--
-->
AnD THIS one Too
                     <--
-->and this one too<--
```

Answer (score 0):

One obvious possibility would be to pass iterators (or ranges) for both the source and the destination of the transformation. If you pass the same range for both the source and the destination, it transforms in place. If you pass separate source and destinations, the destination is separate from the source.

```
// copy transformation
std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out), 
    [](auto x) { return transformed(x); });


// in-place transformation:
std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), in.begin(), 
    [](auto x) { return transformed(x); });
```

With ranges, you can get the same basic effect with considerably less syntactical overhead, so those would look something like:

```
// copy transformation
transform(in, result, [](auto x) { return transformed(x); });

// in-place:
transform(in, in, [](auto x) { return transformed(x); });
```

Comment: `std::transform` is not in question here :) `Transform` is just a function name.

Comment: @LogicStuff: Yes, I'm just using it as an example of a function (function template, if you want to get technical) that supports both types of transformation he asked about.

Comment: That's great for STL algorithms, but my inputs aren't containers.  They are custom data types, and primitive types.

Comment: @TrevorHickey: They don't need to be containers. They just need to be things for which you have iterators. For a specific primitive type, you might have something like `void transform(int *in, int *out);`, with essentially the same situation: to do an in-place transformation, you pass the same address for both input and output, but to create a copy, you pass separate `int`s for input and output.

Answer (score 0):

While I totally agreed on the solution of Rostislav, I could not resist the temptation to propose a C++ standard way of cynical solution to this problem.

The idea is, your `Transform` method can return a proxy object to defer the execution of transformation instead of applying the transform immediately. And if the proxy object gets copied to your original type, then you apply the transformation on the copy. If the proxy object does not get copied but destroyed then you apply the transformation on the original object.

Pseudocode looks like this:

```
struct Proxy {
    OriginalObject& ref;
    bool copied;
    operator OriginalObject() {
        OriginalObject copy(ref);
        transform copy;
        copied := true;
        return copy;
    }
    ~Proxy() { 
        if (not copied)
            transform original reference 
     }
};

Proxy Transform(OriginalObject& obj) { ... }
```

And the usage may look like this:

```
OriginalObject copy = Transform(myRef); // proxy gets copied
                                        // therefore transformed the copy
Transform(myRef);// proxy gets destructed, therefore transformed the original

///////////SPOILER ALERT/////////////////
{
    auto cynicCopy = Tranform(myRef);//proxy copied as proxy
    (myRef);//original is retained until proxy gets destroyed
} // proxy gets destroyed, original modified :)
```

We can just remove copy constructor, copy assignment operator, move constructor and move assignment operator for the proxy class and be happy about it. But I like it the cynic way, so I removed copy methods but implemented move methods. Here is my example implementation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T, typename Operation>
//Proxy class for transformations
struct CynicTransform {
    std::reference_wrapper<T> ref;
    Operation op;
    bool opDtor;

    CynicTransform(T& r, Operation o)
        :
        ref(r),
        op(o),
        opDtor(true)
    { }

    CynicTransform(const CynicTransform&) = delete;
    CynicTransform& operator=(const CynicTransform&) = delete;

    CynicTransform(CynicTransform&& ct)
        :
        ref(ct.ref),
        op(ct.op),
        opDtor(ct.opDtor)
    {
        ct.opDtor = false;
    }

    CynicTransform& operator=(CynicTransform&& ct) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(ref, ct.ref);
        swap(op, ct.op);
        swap(opDtor, ct.opDtor);

        return *this;
    }

    ~CynicTransform() {
        if (opDtor) {
            op(ref.get());
        }
    }

    operator T() {
        T copy(ref.get());
        op(copy);
        opDtor = false;

        return copy;
    }
};

template<typename T, typename Operation>
//Provides ease of use for the proxy class
CynicTransform<T, Operation> MakeCynicTransform(T& tref, Operation op)
{
    return CynicTransform<T, Operation>(tref, op);
}

/*example implementation of a transformation method
 *   each of your transformation method may look like this
 */
auto Transform(std::string& strRef) 
{
    return MakeCynicTransform(strRef, [](std::string& strRef) {
        /*modification logic here*/
        strRef += " modified";
    });
}

int main() {
    std::string s("original");

    std::cout << "Initially: " << s << std::endl;

    std::string copy = Transform(s);

    std::cout << "Original: " << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Copy: " << copy << std::endl;

    {
        auto cynicCopy = Transform(s);

        std::cout << "Scope Original: " << s << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Cynic Modified: " << s << std::endl;

    Transform(s);

    std::cout << "At Last: " << s << std::endl;
}
```

Edit: I got my inspiration from the specification of `std::async`, where if you hold on to returned `std::future` then the method behaves the sane way. But if you call `std::async` directly, it becomes a blocking operation.